# jQuery click function to change the table position

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have three table in the *#middlebox* I would like to click the List to push the table to top
For example, now the position of the table is starter -> soup ->seafood.
When i click to the *#seafood_li* The seafood table will show at the top.
All the table will be set as seafood -> starter -> soup.
When i click *#seafood_li* again it will back to normal.
My jQuery code is a function of toggle and hide but i m not sure how to modify it

```
<div class="main">
    <ul class="top_menu" >
        <li class="orderList" id="starter_li">Starter</li>
        <li class="orderList" id="soup_li"> Soup</li>
        <li class="orderList" id="seafood_li">Seafood</li>
        <li class="orderList" id="return_li">Return All</li>
    </ul>
    <div id="middleBox">
        <table class="food_table" id="starters" style="width:100%">
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td>S1</td> 
                    <td>Starter1<br>
                    <td>10</td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    <table class="food_table" id="soups" style="width:100%">
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>1</td>
                <td>Soup1</td>
                <td>4</td>
            </tr>  
        </tbody> 
    </table>
    <table class="food_table" id="seafood" style="width:100%">
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>2</td>
                <td>seafood1</td>
                <td>7</td>
            </tr> 
        </tbody>  
    </table>
</div>
```

jQuery

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".orderList").not("#return_li").on("click", function(e) {
        var elem = $(this);

        $("#" + this.id.slice(0, -3) + "s").fadeToggle(500);
        var color = elem.css('background-color');
        console.log(color);

        if(color === 'rgb(255, 255, 255)') {
            elem.css("background-color", "#05FF0A");
        } else {
            elem.css("background-color", "rgb(255, 255, 255)");
        }
    });

    $("#return_li").click(function() {
        $(".food_table").fadeIn(500);
        $(this).siblings().each(function() {
            $(this).css("background-color","rgb(255,255,255)");
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: You have one unclosed table and two unclosed DIVs. Can you please fix your HTML??

Comment: You cannot close `<td>` using `<br>`. Please fix again your HTML. What have you tried (jQuery) in memorizing the default tables state (in order to reset)? Have you explored the jQuery `.prepend()` method (to prepend a desired table to the `#middleBox` parent?) You're still missing a closing `</div>`

Comment: P.S. What's that empty `<tr></tr>`?

Comment: Do you realize that your LI `Seafood` does not works currently? THat's cause your table ID does not ends in `"s"`. Currently it's ID is `id="seafood"` instead of `id="seafoods"`

Comment: Any way your logic about concatenating a `s` to get the related table is ... way out. You should be more simplistic in using your relating selectors. Tried using `data-*` attributes?

Comment: Here I've created a fixed demo. (the code you've should done) http://jsbin.com/xoxopo/2/edit?html,css,js,console,output. Now what about the green colors?

Comment: If you're hiding your tables on click, what's the purpose of setting it at the first place inside the parent? Than if you click the LI again it should appear at the old place...?!? I'm out of here, good luck!

Comment: Thats why i am asking how to modify it

Comment: Ah, so you don't want it any more to toggle show/hide but instead to prepend your selected table?

Comment: Yea i know because i was trying to omit some code from the original one

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Notice the ID's I've modified in HTML,
added also a bit of CSS...
See the jQuery. I've commented all the interesting parts. Should be clear what it's doing.

by clicking the LI element `this.id.split("table_")[1]` will remove the "table_" portion from the string retrieving the whole table ID:
If i.e: LI's ID is: `table_starters` the retrieved IS is `starters`.

I'm not sure what's your intention with those green colors... but this should get you started.

```js
$(function() { // DOM ready

  var $orderList = $(".orderList");
  var $middleBox = $("#middleBox");
  var originalHTML = $middleBox.html(); // Memorize it!


  $orderList.not("#orderReturn").on("click", function(e) {
    // Retrieve the second pard of the button ID
    // It's the relation to the table
    var tableId = this.id.split("table_")[1]; // See HTML > modified IDs
    $(this).toggleClass("active");            // See CSS!!!
    $("#"+ tableId).prependTo( $middleBox );
  });


  $("#orderReturn").click(function() {
    $orderList.removeClass("active"); // Remove all special classes
    $middleBox.html( originalHTML );  // Restore original (memorized) HTML
  });


});
```

```css
.food_table{
  width:100%;
  background:#eee;
  margin:10px 0;
}
.orderList.active{
  background:#05FF0A;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="main">

  <ul class="top_menu">
    <li class="orderList" id="table_starters">Starter</li>
    <li class="orderList" id="table_soups"> Soup</li>
    <li class="orderList" id="table_seafoods">Seafood</li>
    <li class="orderList" id="orderReturn">Return All</li>
  </ul>

  <div id="middleBox">
    <table class="food_table" id="starters">
      <tr>
        <td>S1</td> 
        <td>Starter1</td>
        <td>10</td>
      </tr>
    </table>
    <table class="food_table" id="soups">
      <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>Soup1</td>
        <td>4</td>
      </tr>   
    </table>
    <table class="food_table" id="seafoods">
      <tr>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>seafood1</td>
        <td>7</td>
      </tr>   
    </table>
  </div> <!-- !#middleBox -->

</div> <!-- !#main -->
```

Comment: I am new to jQuery and i just learn i can this.id.split ! Thank you and your work is well explained ! Sorry for the format and mistake in the post

Comment: No problem, glad we did it after all :) Happy coding. Thx